# Determine the truth value of this statement with nested quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If the domain for all variables consists of all integers.

$$\exists n \forall m(n < m^2)$$

I think the answer is false because if $m = 0$, then the statement is false, right? But the textbook gave me "true" as the answer, so I am confused...

Comment: if $m=0$ then define $n=-1$. indeed, $-1 < 0^2$ and $n < m^2$. An integer is a number without a decimal point. a "whole" number. it does not have to be positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $n$ be any negative integer.